# Obtaining IFFT from frequency domain analytic formula

Tags: matlab, fft, resolution, frequency, sampling

I'm trying to obtain the time domain signal from an analytic formula in frequency domain, specifically, the formula is:

[image: Formula implemented]

The problem arises when implementing an IFFT, since the following impulse response is obtained:

[image: Impulse response]

It is clear that the first part seems to be ok, however, there is a high level of noise and an increasing 'slope' as the signal comes to an end.

Now, when starting in frequency domain, I'm defining a frequency vector, with frequency resolution based on the size of the FFT.

```
%% Sampling Frequency + Size FFt

Fs = 512; %Sampling Frequency
Nfft = 2^12; %FFT Size
df = Fs/Nfft; %Frequency Resolution
f = 0:df:180; %Frequency Vector
```

Then the formula is applied and a frequency vector is obtained. Later an IFFT of size NFFT is applied:

```
%%Obtain impulse response
x = ifft(P_w,Nfft); %P_w is obtained by formula (1)
t = (0:(length(x)-1))/Fs; %Time Vector
```

As soon as I plot the real part of `x`, the result obtained in image 2 is seen.
Is there any advice on how to overcome this?
I mean, I shouldn't be getting that last 'noisy' portion of the signal or am I omitting an error in the code?

EDIT:

I've made a mistake in the frequency vector, actually, it starts from 0:

```
f = 0:df:180; %Frequency Vector
```

Comment: Shouldn't `P_w` be a vector of complex amplitudes instead of frequencies? How do you build `Pn` before applying the formula? For now it's quite hard to answer as this isn't a [mcve]

Comment: In fact it is. I meant that  `P_w`  is the frequency domain signal obtained using the first formula. That is the signal that needs to be transformed into time domain, yielding an impulse response.

Comment: Right, I'd suggest you change "frequency vector" to "frequency domain vector" in your question to avoid misunderstanding. Now how do you build `Pn` before applying your formula? This is crucial..

Comment: For example, `P_w` should be a vector whose first value is real and representing the average of your time domain signal, while the rest should be of the form `[P1 P2 .... Pm 'Optionnal Nyquist term' conj(Pm) .... conj(P2) conj(P1)]` in order for the IFFT to work

Comment: Also, the upper bound of your frequency vector `f` should depend on the FFt size, And it should've negative values (see previous comment)

Comment: You mean `P_w = [P_w , conj(fliplr(P_w))]` with a frequency vector defined as `f = 0:df:Fs/2` used to calculate P_w up to Nyquist Frequency? Then the vector df will be `df = (Fs/2)/Nfft` with `Nfft` the size of the FFT? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Or just calculate the response using `f = -Fs/2:df:Fs/2` with `df = Fs/Nfft`

Answer (score 0):

In my guess, you missed zero-pad on low frequency range under 5Hz, if your P_w is started from 5Hz.

Supposing my guess is right, plz, put 40 zeros in front of P_w before ifft.

40 zeros correspond to 0Hz~4.875Hz range, since df=0.125.

If P_w is column vector : `P_w=[zeros(40,1);P_w];`

If P_w is row vector : `P_w=[zeros(1,40) P_w];`

Comment: I've made a mistake in the frequency vector, actually I get the same 'error' starting from 0Hz. Anyway, thank you very much!